# Change color based on value

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, html.encode

I have a number of fields where I want to display the data in red if it is expired.

`<%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:d}", Model.Subcontract.insurance_GL))%>`

If the date is less than today's date, then I'd want it to display in red.  What is the best way to do this?

***EDIT***
This is for my Detail View.  It's not in a grid.  It's just a listing of the fields for the individual Subcontract.  There's, insurance_GL, insurance_AL, insurance_WC, etc.  Different fields, not the same field repeating in a grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add a class to the field if the value is less than zero.

So I'm not sure what types of HTML elements are wrapping your field values, but using your example I would do this:

```
<span class="<%=(Model.Subcontract.insurance_GL < 0 ? "red" : "black")%>"
  <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:d}", Model.Subcontract.insurance_GL))%>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on how you are rendering your data in the client page.  Are you using asp.net forms, with a GridView?  Are you generating the html for your data yourself?

I usually go about this with css classes.  I'll have a class for flagged items, like this:

```
.late
{
    color: #f00;
}
```

And in the code behind, where my html is being generated, if you're creating all the html yourself:

```
foreach(Item item in items)
{
    string cls = "";
    if (item.IsLate)
        cls = " class='late'";
    html += "<div" + cls + ">" + item.Text + "</div>";
}
```

That will create `<div>Item1</div>` for a non-late item, and `<div class="late">Item2</div>` for a late item.  You can also have a class for non-late items, if you want them to be styled a certain way too.  Easy enough.

If the items you're flagging are server controls, and you're not creating the html yourself, you can assign a class to them:

```
if (item1.IsLate)
    myTextBox.CssClass = "late";
```

If your data is bound to a GridView, you can have an event handler for `RowDataBound`, and do something like this:

```
protected void gridview_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Item item = e.Row.DataItem as Item;
        if (item.IsLate)
            e.Row.CssClass = "late";
    }
}
```

You could also apply the styling to an individual cell in the GridView:

```
// 3rd cell
e.Row.Cells[2].CssClass = "late";
```

Hope one of these fits your scenario.